# Twilio in nodejs is giving "To: undefined error" and is not able to understand data from front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, backend

I just started using Twilio services and there have been a few challenges. The phone number I send from the front end, I'm not able to make out if its actually being sent to the backend route. Whenever the GET request is done, it throws an error

": Required parameter "opts['to']" missing. twilio".

The first error is what I am getting now.

My form sends this to the backend:

```
 case 2:
            const Phoneno = {
          phone:countryCode+PhoneNumber
        };
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/otp', { data :Phoneno });
        console.log(Phoneno)
```

my route for sending otp:

```
 router.post('/otp', async(req, res)=>{
    client.verify.v2.services("VERIFY_SERVICE_SID")
                .verifications
                .create({to:req.body.phone, channel: 'sms'})
                .then((verification) => {
                  console.log(verification.status);
                  return callback(null);
                }).catch((e) => {
                  console.log(e);
                  return callback(e);

                });
});
```

In that console.log, I get this,

```
"{phone: '+91**********'}
phone: "+91**********"(my actual number) 
[[Prototype]]: Object"
```

Also, when I hardcode the phone number, the route works perfectly fine. And when i send an HTTP request to the route, then also it sends an otp to my phone number. But is not able to recognize the data sent from the frontend.
My http request:

```
  POST http://localhost:4000/app/otp
    Content-Type: application/json
    
    {
    "Phoneno":"+9199********" 
    }
```

Please help me out. Thanks a lot for looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a `GET` request to your back-end, but you are trying to get the data from the request body. `GET` requests do not have a body.

You're also trying to send the data by passing it in an object as the second argument to `axios.get`, but that argument should be a [config object](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config). To send the data in the query for the `GET` request it should be under the `params` key for that object:

```js
            const Phoneno = {
              phone:countryCode+PhoneNumber
            };
            axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/otp', { params: Phoneno });
```

Then on the back-end, read the data from the query, using `req.query.phone`:

```js
router.get('/otp', async(req, res)=>{
    client.verify.v2.services(VERIFY_SERVICE_SID)
                .verifications
                .create({to:req.query.phone, channel: 'sms'})
                .then((verification) => {
                  console.log(verification.status);
                  return callback(null);
                }).catch((e) => {
                  console.log(e);
                  return callback(e);

                });
```

However, this might not be a good idea because an attacker can easily create a URL to your site and add the phone number in the query parameters and use it to perform [SMS pumping](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/preventing-toll-fraud#what-is-sms-pumping).

I'd actually recommend you change your back-end to a `POST` request and send the data from the front end in a `POST` request with the data in the body of the request:

```js
            const Phoneno = {
              phone:countryCode+PhoneNumber
            };
            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/otp', { data: Phoneno });
```

```js
router.post('/otp', async(req, res)=>{
    client.verify.v2.services(VERIFY_SERVICE_SID)
                .verifications
                .create({to:req.body.data.phone, channel: 'sms'})
                .then((verification) => {
                  console.log(verification.status);
                  return callback(null);
                }).catch((e) => {
                  console.log(e);
                  return callback(e);

                });
```

Comment: I made your changes... but still getting the same error. throw new Error('Required parameter "opts[\'to\']" missing.'); ^ Error: Required parameter "opts['to']" missing. And this is referring to the node module of twilio. if i'm sending the data using an http request as follows, "GET localhost:4000/app/otp Content-Type: application/json { "phone":"+91990*******" }" This works perfectly fine tho. but when i send from the frontend, i get the error.

Comment: The issue is not with the Twilio library, but how you are passing the `to` parameter to it. From your comment, it looks like you are still crafting an HTTP GET request with a request body, which should not work. What, of my changes above, did you make? Can you edit your question with the current code that you are using?

Comment: @phinash Yes i made your changes and still the code isn't working properly. Its thrpwing the same error. throw new Error('Required parameter  "opts[\'to\']" missing.'); ^ Error: Required parameter "opts['to']" missing. I edited the question with the current code as you requested

Comment: What body parsing middleware are you using? And what do you see if you `console.log(req.body)` on the server side?

Comment: I'm not using any body parsing middleware since i was able to send the other data from the form to the routes without it. Like to store in the database. As you said i did console.log(req.body) and i got the response { data: { phone : '+9199********' } }

Comment: Ok, if `console.log(req.body)` gave you that object, then you need to use `req.body.data.phone` to get the phone number. I'll update my answer.